# stuck in composite design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

**Practice problem question:**

Following is a possible implementation of the Command design pattern in a game such as PacMan. In this particular version of the PacMan game, the user can issue commands to move PacMan in any of four directions (right, left, up, down). There is also a separate command for attacking other actors, such as GHOSTS, that happen to be in the same location. The Receiver for all commands is PACMAN (not shown).

You are now asked to implement a new requirement that allows the user to define
macros, i.e. combinations of commands that can be executed as one command. Following are three examples of such macro commands:

1. A macro command called “southwest” would be a combination of two commands: down, left.
2. A macro command called “northeast” would be a combination of two commands: right, up.
3. A macro command called "northeast attack” would be a combination of three
   commands: northeast, attack, southwest.

Describe how you would modify this part of the system’s design in order to accommodate the new requirement. Do not be concerned with user interface changes, such as how will the GUI be modified to allow the user to define macros. You must also describe why you believe the modified design is the most appropriate solution.

Indicate clearly how a macro command such as “northeast” will be implemented (pseudo-Eiffel code is sufficient).

**My attempt:**

I used composite design pattern because each of new macro command is composite of single commands like up, left, right or down.

So what I did was I created another class composite_command in which I added the list of commands.

From composite_command, new macro commands classes such as northeast will inherit from it and in execute method of "northeast" I would loop over the children list and call their execute method.like children[i].execute so when the client creates a macro object, it can then pass right and up which will be added to northeast children list and execute will call their children's execute.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: The way you ask the question sounds like you've written the code... but not actually submitted it yet. Surely you can just ask your teacher / lecturer whether your general **approach** is what they're looking for?

Comment: its a practice problem for exam, we are not required to write the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a correct. I've provided example implementation in C#:

```
class Program
{
    public interface Command
    {
        void Execute();
    }

    public class LeftCommand : Command
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Going left");
        }
    }

    public class DownCommand : Command
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Going down");
        }
    }

    public class SouthWestMacroCommand : Command
    {
        IEnumerable<Command> _commands;

        public SouthWestMacroCommand(IEnumerable<Command> commands)
        {
            this._commands = commands;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            foreach(var command in _commands)
            {
                command.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        LeftCommand leftCommand = new LeftCommand();
        DownCommand downCommand = new DownCommand();
        SouthWestMacroCommand southWestCommand = new SouthWestMacroCommand(new List<Command>() { leftCommand, downCommand });
        southWestCommand.Execute();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

> You must also describe why you believe the modified design is the most appropriate solution.

Because it promotes code reuse and there is less chance you will break something. Also the client doesn't need to be changed, because macro commands are also commands.

Comment: thank bro,i really appreciate it ... bro i would highly highly appreciate if you could tell me some similar advanges for using pattern like visitor,observer,state and strategy i would be very thank ful to u. so that in exam if i use any of these i could reason like way you gave reason for using composite:)

Comment: Are you asking me about advantages of these patterns in general or in the context of your problem with macro?

Comment: in general if prof ask me in exam why u used certain patterns so i really liked your reasoning above for why i chose this design if you could telll me for other patterns if i use what reasoning to use although i know advantages of pattenrs, in terms of when we use but above reason u gave is something i am looking for

Comment: Visitor pattern let's you add operations to composite without changing it's structure.

Comment: I've pressed enter by mistake. Rest of patterns:

Observer pattern allows interaction between loosely coupled objects.

State pattern - you localize any changes that will need to be made

Strategy pattern - favors composition over inheritance (more flexible design) and let's you change algorithm at runtime rather than at compile time.

Comment: i always get confused how to know when to use state and strategy pattern, as both look same, in both i can change state during runtime how we figure out any tips

Comment: State pattern and strategy pattern differ in intention. The biggest difference is that state pattern has well defined state transitions (from A to B etc.) while strategy doesn't. Strategy just "gives" an algorithm to the object.

Comment: thank u so much. And do u know anything about mathematical abstractions like REL[G,H] OR SET[G] or FUN[S,G] i wana know when to use them

Comment: No, I don't. Good luck at the exam!